# Unexpected result with tempfiles and hashes

Tags: python, asynchronous, python-asyncio, hashlib

Why does this code encode all files with the same hash?

```
import asyncio
import wget
import hashlib
import os
import tempfile
import zipfile
from multiprocessing import Pool

async def main() -> None:
    url = "https://gitea.radium.group/radium/project-configuration/archive/master.zip"
    if not os.path.isdir('tempdir'):
        os.makedirs('tempdir')
    os.chdir('tempdir')
    wget.download(url)
    zipfile.ZipFile("project-configuration-master.zip").extractall('.')
    os.chdir("project-configuration/nitpick")

async def result():
    for i in range(2):
        task = asyncio.create_task(main())
        await task
        os.chdir("../..")
        for f in os.listdir():
            print(hashlib.sha256(b'{f}'))
        os.remove("tempfile")

asyncio.run(result())
```

Number of encoded files in one pass of the loop 8 but in the end it gets an error after outputting 22 file hashes, and it should be 24:

Comment: I get `FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'tempfile'`, and only one print: `<sha256 _hashlib.HASH object @ 0x7f7b06befe30>`. Please provide a [mre].

Comment: Try not doing all those `chdir()` calls. If you want to access a file in a subdirectory, use a relative pathname.

Answer (score 0):

While working on the example that would clean up the directory handling, I found out your main perceived problem: you are passing the file **names** to hashlib.sha256  - were you most likely wan to pass the file *contents* - My example bellow underscores that, and since I switched to use the more modern "pathlib", also use its functionalities to read each file contents.

Now, for my initial findings when first glancing at your script:

You are using `os.chdir`  which changes a global application state - it looks like you are expecting each task there would have it  is independent working directory, so that `os.chdir` would just change into the same directories across calls.

Not - the first call there switches the whole application into your zip-extracted sub directories. The second call to main will take place when the app is already *inside* that directory.

If it works at all (I'd have to run it, or track the results line by line), you will have all your results deeply nested in recursive `tempdir/project-configuration/nitpick` directories.

Second thing, maybe not related with your question, but this code is not concurrent at all: you put `async def` for your `main` function, but in no point in there there is another asynchronous call (characterized by the `await`) keyword: the function will just run to completion before the asyncio loop can switch to another task.

The `wget` call in this case would be the natural call to be made async there - it being a 3rdy party lib, check its docs if there is an equivalent async call - that would do it. Otherwise, you can run it in another thread with asyncio's `loop.run_in_executor` - that would also make the code concurrent.

Given the structure here, I suppose you tried to adapt code that was using mutiprocessing at one time: if `main` was run in a different process for each task, each one would have a separate working dir, and calls to `wget` would depend only on the OS parallelizing the processes execution: everything would indeed work. Not the case for asyncio code.

So, touching only these two parts, here is how your code could look like. First thing: not ever use `os.chdir`: it will *always* break in anything more complex than a 10 liner script (and in this case, it could break even earlier than that) - as it depends on changing a single, non-restorable, global estate for the process. Always work with relative paths, and concatenate your paths instead. The traditional API for that - `os.path.join` is too verbose, but from Python 3.5 we have `pathlib.Path`  which allows the use of the `/` operator to concatenate paths properly.

```
import asyncio
import wget
import hashlib
import os
import tempfile
import zipfile
from pathlib import Path
from functools import partial
import shutil


TEMPDIR = Path("tempdir")
CONFIGDIR = "project-configuration/nitpick"

async def main() -> None:
    url = "https://gitea.radium.group/radium/project-configuration/archive/master.zip"
    if not TEMPDIR.is_dir():    # is_dir is a method from Path objects
        TEMPDIR.mkdir()
    #wget.download(url, out=str(TEMPDIR))  
                # I had to check wget's source: it is a small utility which was not updated to  understand pathlib
                # objects. But it can take an output directory argument, like above, avoiding the use of `chdir`
                # Nonetheless this has to be made an async call with:
                
    loop = asyncio.get_running_loop()
    await loop.run_in_executor(None, partial(wget.download, url, out=str(TEMPDIR)))
            # The above call is asyncio friendly: it sends the wget workload
            # to another thread, in a transparent way, so that other tasks
            # can run concurrently to that
                                        
    zipfile.ZipFile(TEMPDIR / "project-configuration-master.zip").extractall(TEMPDIR)
    # os.chdir("project-configuration/nitpick")  # as discussed: do not do this.
    # instead, change all your file operations from this point down to prepending
    # `TEMPDIR / CONFIGDIR / "filename" ` from this point on. Calls with this to 
    # legacy functions may require it to be converted to a str -
    # `str(TEMPDIR / CONFIGDIR / "filename")`, but "open" and other 
    # Python file operations will work just fine.
    # ...

async def result():
    for i in range(2):
        task = asyncio.create_task(main())
        await task  # This will just perform all ops in sequence, not paralleizing anything
                    # but if you are parallelizing things, you might want to 
                    # parametrize tempdir - as is, the code will use the same
                    # hardcoded "tempdir" for all downloads
        # os.chdir("../..")  # No directory changed in the call - no need to change back
        for f in TEMPDIR.iterdir():  # yields all entries in directory 
            # print(hashlib.sha256(b'{f}'))  # Here is your main problem: you are really calling hashlib on the FILENAME
            hash_ = hashlib.sha256(f.read_bytes()) # here we calculate the hash on the file _contents_ 
            print(f.name, hash_.hexdigest()) # and print the actual hash, not the python repr of the hash object
        shutil.rmtree(TEMPDIR)

asyncio.run(result())
```